# FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0: subnormal <op> normal can produce subnormal?

Tags: c

ISO/IEC 9899:202x (E) working draft — February 5, 2020 C17..C2x N2479:

> The presence or absence of subnormal numbers is characterized by the implementation-defined
> values of FLT_HAS_SUBNORM, DBL_HAS_SUBNORM, and LDBL_HAS_SUBNORM:
>
> −1 indeterminable 27)
>
> 0 absent (type does not support subnormal numbers) 28)
>
> 1 present (type does support subnormal numbers)
>
> 28) Characterization as absent is intended if no floating-point operations produce subnormal results from non-subnormal inputs, even if the type format includes representations of subnormal numbers.

In other words `28)` says: `if FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0, then any_normal <op> any_normal never produces subnormal`.

However, due to the presence of `from non-subnormal inputs` we can deduce that `if FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0, then some_subnormal <op> some_normal may produce subnormal`. Which is weird, because:

1. It is compatible with the `characterization as absent` (i.e. `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0`).
2. It `may produce subnormal` even if `type does not support subnormal numbers`.

Can someone explain / resolve the weirdness?

Comment: I don't see a problem.  Footnote 28 clarifies that the wording "does not support" is intended to include situations where the type *does* support them but the compiler will not produce them of its own accord.  Maybe it wasn't the best choice of wording but the footnote seems to make the situation clear.  But if you deliberately feed it subnormals anyway then all bets are off.

Comment: I can always create a subnormal representation by manipulating bits, or by reading a value from a file.

Comment: @stark There is a conclusion that if FLT_HAS_SUBNORM (or DBL) is 0, then such `manually constructed` FP objects (via type punning, memcpy(), reading from file, etc.) lead to UB. See stackoverflow.com/a/65296492/9881330.

Comment: As I read it: `DBL_MIN/4.0` with `DBL_HAS_SUBNORM == 1` produces a subnormal.  I'd expect with `DBL_HAS_SUBNORM == 0` to produce 0.0 (with round to nearest).  Yet `pow(2.0, DBL_MIN_EXP -  2)` may produce a sub-normal in both cases as it is a function and not an operation.

Comment: @stark Correction: "... then executing FP operations with such manually constructed FP objects used as inputs seems lead to UB".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0: subnormal <op> normal` can produce `subnormal`?

Yes, but it will be under UB.

=== Why it will be under UB ===

The C standard is quite restrained about `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0` case. All that is says about `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0` is:

> absent (type does not support subnormal numbers)

> Characterization as absent is intended if no floating-point operations produce subnormal results from non-subnormal inputs, even if the type format includes representations of subnormal numbers.

Which can be interpreted as:

> `If FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0, then any_normal <op> any_normal never produces subnormal`.

The C standard seems to omit explicit definition of behavior for the following case (formulated as a question):

> In case if `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0`: does execution of FP operations with inputs represented by manually constructed subnormals (using type punning via union, using memcpy(), reading from file, etc.) lead to undefined behavior (UB)?

If the explicit definition of behavior is omitted, then according to the C standard:

> … Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this document… by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior…